# ハミルトニアン・モンテカルロ法の実装関数が型異常を起こす

Tags: julia

現在、須山敦志「Juliaで作って学ぶベイズ統計学」(第1刷)を参照しながらJuliaでのハミルトニアン・モンテカルロ法を実装しています。ですが、P.190-195に掲載されているとおりに実装し、実例の線形回帰(同書P.196)を計算させても型異常で上手く動作しません。

残念ながらJuliaに未習熟でこれ以上自分で解決できないため、こちらで伺います。正常に動作させるためにどうしたら良いかアドバイス頂けますならば幸甚です。
なおσ = 1.0,μ₁ = 0.0,μ₂ = 0.0,σ₁ = 10.0およびσ₂ = 10.0はエラーを起こすのが明らかだったので、本書中に記載が無いのですが自分で追加しました。また書籍の実装はVer.1.6.1で、自身はVer.1.6.2およびVer.1.8.0で検証しています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

```
using Distributions, PyPlot, ForwardDiff, LinearAlgebra

# n次元単位行列
eye(n) = Diagonal{Float64}(I, n)

# グラフの諸設定を行う関数
function set_options(ax, xlabel, ylabel, title;
                      grid = true, gridy = false, legend = false)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    ax.set_title(title)
    if grid
        if gridy
            ax.grid(axis = "y")
        else
            ax.grid()
        end
    end
    legend && ax.legend()
end

# ガウス分布を提案分布としたMetropolis-Hasting法
function GaussianMH(log_p_tilde, μ₀;
        maxiter::Int64, σ::Float64)
    # サンプルを格納する配列
    D = length(μ₀)
    μ_samples = Array{typeof(μ₀[1]), 2}(undef, D, maxiter)

    μ_samples[:,1] = μ₀

    # 受容サンプル数
    num_accepted = 1

    for i in 2:maxiter
    #
        μ_tmp = rand(MvNormal(μ_samples[:, i-1], σ*eye(D)))
    
        # 比率 r
        log_r = (log_p_tilde(μ_tmp) +
                 logpdf(MvNormal(μ_tmp, σ), μ_samples[:, i-1])) -
                (log_p_tilde(μ_samples[:, i-1]) + 
                 logpdf(MvNormal(μ_samples[:,i-1], σ), μ_tmp))
        #
        is_accepted = min(1, exp(log_r)) > rand()
        new_sample = is_accepted ? μ_tmp : μ_samples[:, i-1]
    
        #
        μ_samples[:, i] = new_sample
    
        #
        num_accepted += is_accepted
    end

    μ_samples, num_accepted
end

# Hamiltonian Monte Carlo method
function HMC(log_p_tilde, μ₀, maxiter::Int64, L::Int64, ε::Float64)
    # leapfrog による値の更新
    function leapflog(grad, p_in,μ_in, L, ε)
        μ=μ_in
        p = p_in + 0.5 *ε*grad(μ)
        for l in 1: L-1
            μ +=ε*p
            p += ε*grad(μ)
        end
        μ += ε*p
        p += 0.5 *ε*grad(μ)
        p, μ
    end
    
    # 非正規化対数事後分布の勾配関数
    grad(μ) = ForwardDiff.gradient(log_p_tilde, μ)
    
    # サンプルを格納する配列
    D = length(μ₀)
    μ_samples = Array{typeof(μ₀[1]), 2}(undef, D, maxiter)
    
    # 初期サンプル
    μ_samples[:, 1] = μ₀
    
    # 受容されたサンプル数
    num_accepted = 1
    
    for i in 2:maxiter
        # 運動量の生成
        p_in = randn(size(μ₀))
        
        # リープフロッグ
        p_out, μ_out = leapflog(grad, p_in, μ_samples[:, i-1], L, ε)
        
        # 比率rの対数を計算
        μ_in = μ_samples[:, i-1]
        log_r = (log_p_tilde(μ_out) + 
                 logpdf(MvNormal(zeros(D),eye(D)), vec(p_out))) -
                (log_p_tilde(μ_in) + 
                 logpdf(MvNormal(zeros(D),eye(D)),vec(p_in)))
                
        # 確率rでサンプル受容
        is_accepted = min(1, exp(log_r)) > rand()
        new_sample = is_accepted ? μ_out : μ_in
        
        # 新サンプルを格納
        μ_samples[:,i] = new_sample
        
        # 受容された場合、合計を加算する
        num_accepted += is_accepted
    end
    
    μ_samples, num_accepted
end

### ラッパー関数 ###
function inference_wrapper_GMH(log_joint, params, w_init, maxiter::Int64 = 100_000, σ::Float64 = 1.0)
    ulp(w) = log_joint(w, params)
    GaussianMH(ulp, w_init, maxiter = maxiter, σ = σ)
end

function inference_wrapper_HMC(log_joint, params, w_init,maxiter::Int64 = 100_000, L::Int64 = 100, ε::Float64 = 1e-1)
    ulp(w) = log_joint(w, params)
    HMC(ulp, w_init, maxiter = maxiter, L=L, ε=ε)
end

###
X_obs = [-2, 1, 5]
Y_obs = [-2.2, -1.0, 1.5]

## 以下5つのパラメータは本書には無し
σ = 1.0
μ₁ = 0.0
μ₂ = 0.0
σ₁ = 10.0
σ₂ = 10.0

log_joint(w, X, Y, σ, μ₁,σ₁,μ₂,σ₂) =
          sum(logpdf.(Normal.(w[1]*X .+ w[2],σ), Y)) +
          logpdf(Normal(μ₁,σ₁), w[1]) +
          logpdf(Normal(μ₂,σ₂), w[2])
params = (X_obs, Y_obs, σ, μ₁, σ₁,μ₂,σ₂)

ulp(w) = log_joint(w, params...)



###
# 初期値
w_init = randn(2)

param_posterior_GMH, num_accepted_GMH = 
    inference_wrapper_GMH(log_joint, params, w_init, maxiter = 300, σ = 1.0)
param_posterior_HMC, num_accepted_HMC = 
    inference_wrapper_HMC(log_joint, params, w_init, maxiter = 300, L = 10, ε = 1e-1)

# 
fig, axes = subplots(2,1,figsize=(8,4))

axes[1].plot(param_posterior_GMH[1,:])
set_options(axes[1], "iteration", "w₁", "w₁ sequence (GMH)")

axes[2].plot(param_posterior_GMH[2,:])
set_options(axes[2], "iteration", "w₂", "w₂ sequence (GMH)")

tight_layout()
println("acceptance rate (GMH) = $(num_accepted_GMH/maxiter)")
```

Comment: 書籍と同じバージョンでも同様のエラーが発生するのでしょうか？（出来るだけ書籍で動作確認済みの環境にした方が躓きは少ないかと思います。）

Comment: ありがとうございます。仰ることはごもっともかと存じます。ただ書籍と同じバージョンにすると、今度は引数の値であるσ = 1.0,μ₁ = 0.0,μ₂ = 0.0,σ₁ = 10.0およびσ₂ = 10.0が未定義であることが問題でエラーが起こるため、書籍から変えた次第です。

Comment: 書籍に不備があるのであれば出版社に連絡されると良いかと思います。先ほど確認した限りでは正誤表はないようでしたので。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。どうやら自分がキーワード引数を理解しておらず、セミコロンをしっかり使っていなかったことが問題だった様子で、解決いたしました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーメッセージを見ると`got unsupported keyword arguments`ですので型ではなくキーワード引数の問題のようです。

質問のコードを見ると、`inference_wrapper_GMH`のキーワード引数の前に`;`が抜けているようです。（`inference_wrapper_HMC`も同様）

Comment: ありがとうございます。これで当初のエラーは解決いたしました。心より御礼申し上げます。もっとも今度はlog_joint()で同様のエラーが出てしまったのですが苦笑